# WordPress HTML code, help to find

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Creating web-site on WordPress, and got problem with finding HTML code of current part.

[Web site here](https://elite-remont.com)

Need to change Services titles and descriptions, but can find this part of code on FTP server. Is it possible to find it? Here the structure of ftp

[image][image]

i supose it must be in index.php, or index-servise.php, i was cheking this files(and all other) there is only functional part of this blocks. Can anybody help me to find this HTML code?

Comment: Download all your theme files and search them. If it's not in your theme files, then it might be stored in the database, and you should be able to edit the values when logged into `/wp-admin/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<head>` tag of your page is located in the **header.php** file of the current theme you are using. Your theme files are located inside the **/wp-content/themes/**. You can edit there. To see which theme you are using, access your WP-ADMIN and navigate to Appearence > Themes.

The Services seem to be generated as Widgets, so you should find them in Appearence > Widgets. These are stored in the MySQL database and are not hardcoded in HTML.